# ASP.Net web application cannot read a file within folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

In my asp.net web application, I read the xml file for obtaining a key. If file is not present I show a form to enter the key details and then create the file.

**First problem**: My app does not recognize the file even if its there.

**Second problem**: I am running application on the server. When writing, rather overwriting the file, browser shows the username, password prompt before writing the file. If I enter admin credentials it allows to create a file.

I have checked all possible combinations of permissions on the file / folders, but could not resolve the problem.

Any ideas, what I could be missing here?

Comment: Every Windows operation (accessing file system) needs an account and the proper permissions. In your case, identify the account and its read/write permissions on the target folders/files first, and then come back to the issue.

Comment: please add some code of how you are trying to achieve this. just a text description is not enough generally while asking questions in stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

You read the xml file but is it as a part of your solution? If yes, are you reading it through relative path i.e. are you using Server.MapPath to read it like  Server.MapPath("~/Files.test.xml")? Once you use relative path, I don't think it will ask you credentials as it still is in your project directory.

It should work. I am also reading and writing files in my web application.

If it still does not work, please tell me the way you are reading file.

Thanks,